Error in PipeOp high cardinality factor encoding using mlr3: Invalid 'col_roles' Names
I am trying to train a glmnet model using data that includes a categorical variable, with the mlr3 package. Since the categorical variable has 27 levels, I considered it as a high-cardinality feature and used impact encoding. However, I am getting the following error message:
Error in .__Task__col_roles(self = self, private = private, super = super,  : 
  Assertion on 'names of col_roles' failed: Names must be a permutation of set {'feature','target','name','order','stratum','group','weight','coordinate','space','time'}, but has extra elements {'always_included'}.
This happened PipeOp high_cardinality_encoding's $train()

Here is my code:
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/test.csv")
data$presence <- as.factor(data$presence)
data$habitat <- as.factor(data$habitat)
classif_task_sp <- mlr3spatial::as_task_classif_st(id = "A1", x = data[, which(!(names(data) %in% c("ID", "year")))], target = "presence", positive = "1", 
                                                   coordinate_names = c("x", "y"), crs = "EPSG:4326", coords_as_features = FALSE)
classif_task_sp$set_col_roles("presence", roles = c("target", "stratum"))
partition_classif_task_sp <- mlr3::partition(classif_task_sp, ratio = 0.67)

factor_encoding <- mlr3pipelines::po("removeconstants") %>>%
  ## mlr3pipelines::po("collapsefactors", no_collapse_above_prevalence = 0.01) %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encodeimpact", affect_columns = selector_cardinality_greater_than(10), id = "high_cardinality_encoding") %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encode", method = "one-hot", affect_columns = selector_cardinality_greater_than(3), id = "low_cardinality_encoding") %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encode", method = "treatment", affect_columns = selector_type("factor"), id = "binary_encoding")

learner_glmnet <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob", standardize = FALSE))
learner_glmnet_factor_encoding <- mlr3::as_learner(factor_encoding %>>% learner_glmnet)

tuning <- mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = mlr3tuning::tnr("grid_search", resolution = 5, batch_size = 10),
                                 learner = learner_glmnet_factor_encoding,
                                 resampling = mlr3::rsmp("spcv_coords", folds = 2),
                                 measure = mlr3::msr("classif.prauc"),
                                 terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 2, k = 0))

run_resampling <- mlr3::resample(classif_task_sp, learner = tuning, resampling = mlr3::rsmp("spcv_coords", folds = 2), store_models = TRUE)

run_training <- tuning$train(classif_task_sp, row_ids = partition_classif_task_sp$train)

Here is the dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rfyj9oav5z5yipmkr4a9q/test.csv?rlkey=vsfsyhfgh4svnoos5z6t18u5q&st=vak2wayv&dl=0
Update:
I updated the packages to have mlr3 0.21.1 and mlr3fselect 1.2.1, but I'm still getting the error message:


Can you try to update your packages? This was a bug that was solved with mlr3 0.21.1 and mlr3fselect 1.2.1.

Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, of course. I installed the new versions of these packages, but I'm still getting the error message.

Did you restart RStudio after updating the packages? It works for me. If the error is still there please open a bug report https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues. Thanks!
